# Method delivering different types

Tags: php

I use a library where a method returns different types depending on the arguments you pass to it, let's say:

```
// returns string when you pass "foo" to the method
$string = $obj->useMethod("foo");

// returns an array when you pass "bar" to the method
$array = $obj->useMethod("bar");
```

I'm no PHP object specialist but I have the impression that this is not really convenient (you should know in advance what is going to be returned). Is this something standard ? or should it be avoided at all ?

Comment: This is just a bad design.

Comment: it's impossible to help you if you can't provide any of the method's code, how should we be able to figure out what's wrong if we don't know what your method does.

Comment: actually I just searched for an advice about what is standard and what is not. I mean, do you, as php programmers sometimes produce such methods or is this something that you would not really do (okay for closing if this is far too general question)

Comment: Generally saying there's never right or wrong, it all depends on your application / your needs. But obviously, if your function produces an output you weren't expecting, there's something wrong in the code of that function, and we can't help u without knowing anything bout nothing

Answer (score 1):

Surely is not very well designed, but it is perfectly legal. Even some php core methods have this behaviour (ex: `parse_url` can return an array if the second parameter is not set, a string if set, `false` if an error is encountered)

Answer (score 0):

This is bad practice and should be avoided. PHP now supports type hinting and it's good practice to use them.

e.g.

```
class SomePaymentService implements PaymentServiceInterface
{
    
    public function processPayment(array $parameters): array
    {
        // Process a payment
        
        return [
            // results
        ];
    }
}
```